# Microsoft flow gateways issue using HTTPS

Tags: https, microsoft-flow

I read this article https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/gateway-reference/

> Microsoft SharePoint data gateways only support HTTP traffic; they do
>   not support HTTPS traffic

Any ideas guys to use data gateways for HTTPS protocols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it don't support HTTPS, it's a clear statement

> Microsoft SharePoint data gateways only support HTTP traffic; they do
>   not support HTTPS traffic

Meanwhile, I think extending the web application may be overcome this issue:

**Note:**

- When the web application is extended, a different Web Application and IIS are created So you can use `HTTP` instead of `HTTPS`.
- The main Web Application and the extended one will **share** the same Content Database.

**To extend the web application:**

- Open Central Administration > Application Management > Manage web applications.
- Select the source web application and from the above ribbon click on Extend button.

[image]

- The Extend Web Application dialog will be shown, Fill the required information based on your requirements

For more details check [SharePoint 2016: Extend A Web Application](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/06/17/sharepoint-2016-extend-web-application/)